# Use omp simd without a for

Tags: openmp, vectorization

I have the following instructions:

```
unsigned long int xDiff = seq1.x ^ seq2.x;
unsigned long int yDiff = seq1.y ^ seq2.y;
unsigned long int zDiff = seq1.z ^ seq2.z;
```

It's possible to vectorize this using `omp simd`?

Comment: How are your variables declared? Do you really need to vectorize just three operations? Are they in a loop?

Comment: @VladimirF It's an ulong3 struct from cuda_api (the code run in both cuda and XeonPhi). And yes it's inside a while(that cannot be transformed in a form).

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you define the positions as an array, you don't need to do anything, the compiler will vectorize it for you.

```
struct position {
  unsigned long pos[3];
};

struct position foo( struct position seq1, struct position seq2) {
  struct position diff;

  for( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i )
    diff.pos[i] = seq1.pos[i] ^ seq2.pos[i];

  return diff;
}
```

GCC since 4.6 will vectorize it using just `-O3` flag. If you provide architecture specific flags (for example with Intel vector extensions: `-msse42`, `-mavx`, etc.), you can control which vector instruction set the compiler has to use. If you want just to build for your own machine, you can compile with `-march=native`.

```
foo(position, position):
    movdqu  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+32]
    mov     rax, rdi
    movdqu  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp+8]
    pxor    xmm0, xmm1
    movdqu  XMMWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0
    ret
```

If you "unroll the loop manually" (like in your example)

```
diff.pos[0] = seq1.pos[0] ^ seq2.pos[0];
diff.pos[1] = seq1.pos[1] ^ seq2.pos[1];
diff.pos[2] = seq1.pos[2] ^ seq2.pos[2];
```

This is no longer the case:

```
foo(position, position):
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+32]
    xor     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
    mov     rax, rdi
    mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+40]
    xor     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+16]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+8], rdx
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+48]
    xor     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+24]
    mov     QWORD PTR [rdi+16], rdx
    ret
```

Also, a `#pragma omp simd` directive can only be applied to loops:

> simd [2.8.1] Applied to a loop to indicate that the loop can be transformed into a SIMD loop.

```
#pragma omp simd [clause[,] clause] ...]
  for-loops
```